# How can I fix the mixed content problems of the kk star ratings plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, ssl, https

I recently switched to ssl in order to provide a better and more secure website experience for my users.

I nearly solved all of my mixed content issues, but the mixed content warnings of the Wordpress plugin kk star ratings are still unsolved.

When I open a blog post, I always get the following notifications:

**The following content is displayed in an insecure manner.**

/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/yellow.png.

/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/gray.png.

I've already looked into the plugin folder, but I don't have any php knowledge to fix it.

Could these lines be responsible for the mixed content warning?

```
echo $star_gray ? '.kk-star-ratings .kksr-star.gray { background-image: url('.$star_gray.'); }' : '';

echo $star_yellow ? '.kk-star-ratings .kksr-star.yellow { background-image: url('.$star_yellow.'); }' : '';

echo $star_orange ? '.kk-star-ratings .kksr-star.orange { background-image: url('.$star_orange.'); }' : '';
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me to load these files via ssl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself. You have to remove the stars in settings / stars. Afterwards the tool recognizes ssl and will load it from a secure version of the website.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

Can try replacing all URL from database to https, you can use the plugin "Search and replace" or if you have phpMyAdmin access you can use this script

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.yoursite.com','https://www.yoursite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.yoursite.com', 'https://www.yoursite.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.yoursite.com','https://www.yoursite.com');
```

Redirect HTTP to HTTPS Using .htaccess file. You this code to force a redirect to https URL.

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteCond%{HTTPS}off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this not solve the problem because the URL is hardcoded in the CSS, not database.

Answer (score -2):

You can easy do this from your kk star rating dashboard. Just follow this link: https://ask.wpcrons.com/how-can-i-fix-the-mixed-content-problems-of-the-kk-star-ratings-plugin/

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE! Please note that link only answers are not appropriate here. For example, what will happen if the site to that link is out of service? That's why it's important to add part of the text / CODE etc. from the link that'll be sufficient for the answer. You may still provide the link as the original source, but it's better if you also mention your affiliation with the link (if you have any).